# Create dynamic quarter of circle with css

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I need to make this with css and the content inside it will be dynamic. I was trying with border-radius but this property can't make what i need.

[image]

if anyone can help me I would be very grateful.

Comment: This question needs detail. Could you maybe post an example of what you're looking to accomplish, your HTML and CSS, and what you've already tried?

Comment: you need to read about **_SVG_** and **_Canvas_** 
Ref from W3schools:
[About SVG](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_svg.asp) -
[About Canvas](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp)

gdluck

Comment: When asking a question, people will be better able to provide help if you provide code that they can easily understand and use to reproduce the problem.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: maybe you can share what you have, and we can help to refine it. It is definitely do-able with css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the pseudo-elements before and after and one more div for the top right corner, you can make the width dynamic by removing the property max-width of the central div.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/lynconebb/pen/WNGMpoa)

```css
.container {
    position: relative;
    display:inline-block;
}
.central-div {
    background-color:#99e6ff;
    font-size:1.2rem;
    max-width:300px;
    padding: 10px 0 10px 20px;
    margin-left:170px;
}

.central-div::before {
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    background-color:#e6e600;
    height: 100%;
    top:100%;
    left:0;
    width:170px;
    border-radius:0 0 0 100%;
}
.central-div::after {
    content:"";
    top:0;
    left:0;
    position:absolute;
    background-color: #4d0099;
    border-radius:100% 0 0 0;
    height: 100%;
    width:170px;
}
.top-rigth-corner {
    content:"";
    top:0;
    left:100%;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:10;
    background-color: #99e6ff;
    border-radius:0 100% 0 0;
    height: 100%;
    width:170px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="central-div">
        <p>Integer ligula risus, aliquet sit amet risus eu</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, con.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="top-rigth-corner"></div>
</div>
```